# Handle POST request query param from browsable API in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a requirement of having a query param in a POST request with the JSON payload in the body.

Now in django-rest-framework I have been able to do that by overriding the `perform_create` method of ModelViewSet in my view class, but what I can do to have it appear in browsable API. I tried django-filter and its backend but they are geared towards filtering(obviously) in a GET request. I don't want to filter but want to just use that query param as a parameter to run celery tasks during `perform_create`.

This is how my viewset looks right now.

```py
class AbcViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Abc.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AbcSerializer
    filterset_fields = ('fk_field', )


    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        query_param1 = self.request.query_params.get('param', None)
        ...schedule celery task using the query_param1 and save the model...
```

my request for this will be like http://127.0.0.1:8000/abc/?param=xyz

If you notice above I want to be able to fill that`param` using browsable API. Trying to search I have a feeling it will involve creating some kind of HTML view rendering for the param but If its more easier available from browsable API that would definitely help. Right now I don't see any way to send any query params other than filters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call the browsable API with the specific query parameter like for example:

`http://localhost:8000/yoururl?param=111` and when performing the **POST** the `self.request.query_params` will yield `<QueryDict: {'param': ['111']}>`.

Comment: I actually tried it and checked chrome dev tools but I must have done something wrong the first time. This works. Thanks.